# When doing a Git merge, do I need to merge in reverse order of checkouts?

Tags: git

Let's say I have a top-level Git branch "dev" and I create a new feature branch "feature1".

```
git checkout -b feature1 dev
```

Now I decide I need to fix a bug while I'm in this branch so I create a second branch "bug1".

```
git checkout -b bugfix feature1
```

Now I have this branch structure:

```
dev
  feature1
    bug1
```

I want to merge the new feature and bug fix back into my dev branch.  To do this is it necessary to merge each branch in reverse order (i.e. "retrace my steps") like this?

```
git checkout feature1
git merge --no-ff bug1
git checkout dev
git merge --no-ff feature1
```

Or can I simply go from bug1 straight back to dev like this and still pick up the new feature code?

```
git checkout dev
git merge --no-ff bug1
```

Please, no comments on how it would be better to rebase or do it some different way as this is my current workflow and I'm comfortable with it.  If I'm only branching and using checkouts and merges, do both of these have the same effect of adding a new feature and a bug fix to my dev Git branch?

Comment: Have you tried it? On your machine, create a remote and a local folder. In the remote folder, git --bare init, in the local folder, git init. Then from the local folder, set the remote with git remote add origin <path-to-remote> and play around.

Comment: That said, the order does not matter. You won't be able to avoid resolving conflicts by changing the merge order. If bug1 contains all the commits, then merging bug1 is sufficient. Else, merge both in the order you please. Merge bug1 into feature1 and then feature1 into dev. Or bug1 into dev and then feature1 into dev. Or feature1 into dev, then bug1 into dev. Or feature1 into bug1 and then bug1 into dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `feature1` is an ancestor of `bug1` (that is, `bug1` contains all the commits in `feature1`), then merging `bug1` into `dev` will produce identical content (an identical Git tree) as merging `bug1` into `feature1` and then `feature1` into `dev`.

This is because merging `bug1` into `feature1` in this case produces the same Git tree as just `bug1`, since it's equivalent to a fast-forward (just that you indicated you didn't want one). You're essentially creating a merge where one side is unchanged and the other is changed, in which case Git takes all of the changed components.

If there have been additional commits to `feature1` that are not included in `bug1`, then obviously they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Merging `bug1` to `dev` will bring into `dev` all the commits on `bug1`, which includes the commits on `feature1` before your last merge from `feature1` to `bug1`, or if you have never merged from `feature1` to `bug1`, it would be before you created `bug1` off of `feature1`.

In short, if you don't have commits on `feature1` that are not on `bug1`, then you can directly merge from `bug1` to `dev`. Otherwise you'll need to merge both to `dev`, but the order does not matter.